# AngularJs $error.minlength value before type

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using $error.minlength in cell phone input but when I want to validate this input for enabling the button to send a form to the server, $error.minlenght value is null. It shows me nothing until I type something but I need to know before I type anything how to tell angular that my $error.minlength is false;
so I can use this in disable attribute and check the validation of the each input for whole form then Enable the button and send the form to the server.

```html
<input required name="mobileNo" ng-minlength="11" minlength="11" maxlength="11" ng-class="{nessasery:signupForm.mobileNo.$invalid,blur:signupForm.mobileNo.$touched && signupForm.mobileNo.$invalid}" class="form-control" id="tel" type="text" ng-pattern="/^09[0-9]*$/" ng-model="account.mobileno" placeholder="cellphone"/>
                           <span class="msg text-danger" ng-show="signupForm.mobileNo.$touched">
                              <span ng-show="signupForm.mobileNo.$error.required">can't leave this field</span>
                           </span>
                           <span class="msg text-danger" ng-show="signupForm.mobileNo.$dirty">
                              <span class="msg text-danger" ng-show="signupForm.mobileNo.$error.minlength">Total Number Of Phone Number is 11</span>
                              <span class="msg text-danger" ng-show="signupForm.mobileNo.$error.pattern">Enter Valid Phone Number</span>
                           </span>




<button ng-disabled="(signupForm.mobileNo.$error.minlength)">Singup</button>
```

Comment: Please show the entire expression you are using with `ng-disabled` (we can't tell you what's wrong otherwise). Or instead of disabling when the input is invalid, do it when the form is invalid: `ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid"`

Comment: Tnks Man --- it's Worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in angularJS when we need to Validate the form and Enable the button (singup button) , we have two options:

validate the each input of the form or just validate the form element itself.
like This:
[formname].$invalid

```html
<form name="myForm" novalidate >
  
<input name="username" required/>
<input name="password" required />
  
<button type="submit" ng-disable="myForm.username.$invalid && myForm.password.$invalid">sinup<button/>
 
  <form/>
  
  <!-- it,s better to do this:  -->
  <button ng-disable="myForm.$invalid">
```